# Extract (year from timestamp) in MonetDB

Tags: sql, monetdb

I try to extract year from timestamp in monetdb using

```
select extract(year from ts), ts from orders;
```

but this query obviously returns false result:

```
 |   year   |     ts        | 
 ----------------------------
 | 17935405 | 1441695291096 |
 | 18245391 | 1441695601082 |
 | 18331748 | 1441695687439 |
```

Comment: What type is the `ts` column? Is it just an integer number?

Answer (score 1):

If the data type of the `TS` column is just the epoch timestamp, the milliseconds from `1970-01-01 00:00:00.000`, it needs to be converted to a temporal type before the `EXTRACT` will work. According to [this link](https://www.monetdb.org/pipermail/users-list/2008-February/001602.html):

> The convert function is called `epoch(int)`. There is also a new function
>   epoch(timestamp) which returns the number of seconds since epoch.

As I can not verify this without having a MonetDB instance, I researched a bit more, and this seems to be uglier but more likely working to get a timestamp from the epoch time (Based on [this post](https://www.monetdb.org/pipermail/users-list/2005-May/000082.html)):

```
select TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + interval CAST(ts/1000 AS STRING)  seconds from orders;
```

So if this is working, the complete solution would be something like

```
select EXTRACT(YEAR from (TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + interval CAST(ts/1000 AS STRING) seconds)) from orders;
```

**Note: syntax is most likely way off as I have no MonetDB instance to test with**

**Edit:** added CAST(... as STRING) as per [this link](https://www.monetdb.org/pipermail/users-list/2005-May/000086.html) I hope this does work with arithmetics like `ts/1000` without issues...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it isn't working in MonetDb. I got follow error:syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting SCOLON in: "select timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + interval ts"

Comment: It seems that ts must be String but not bigint.

Comment: @AnastasiaOsintseva I added a cast to the answer, could you take a look at it? I still don't have a MonetDB instance to be able to check - so I'm not sure the syntax is actually right. However, by the looks of it, I'm sure there has to be a better method to do so: having to convert stuff to Strings, and back - that is far from efficient...

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working too. The query failed with error: syntax error, unexpected CAST, expecting SCOLON in: "select timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + interval cast". I think with TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + interval should be used only string.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work.

```
select extract(year from (TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + CAST(1441695291096/1000 AS STRING)));
```

...returns:

```
2015
```

...and this:

```
select extract(year from (TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + CAST(1481767624000/1000 AS STRING)));
```

...returns:

```
2016
```

So for your query:

```
select extract(year from ts), ts from orders;
```

...try:

```
select extract(year from (TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + CAST(ts/1000 AS STRING))) as "Year" from orders;
```

...and it should work.

Comment: I was finally able to get this working with your help, but I did have to do `CAST(CAST(unix_date AS BIGINT) AS STRING)`